# Chartjs v2.0: stacked bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I need to get a chart like this:

[image: Example Chart]

I find [this example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/b233c2f0/) but it uses old version of `ChartJs`. I try it using v2.0 but I don't get it.

Can someone post a example?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

With v2.1.x, you can achieve this using the `stacked` option

```
...
options: {
    scales:{
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
        }]
    }
}
...
```

---

**Stack Snippet**

```js
var config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      type: 'line',
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: [-65, -10, -80, -81, -56, -85, 40],
      borderColor: 'black',
      fill: false
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
    }, {
      type: 'bar',
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [-65, 0, -80, -81, -56, -85, -40]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }]
    }
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found project sample: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/bar-stacked.html

Answer (score 43):

After fiddling forever, I finally got it to work, here's a sample. Somebody please update the docs!

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes 1',
        data: [10, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      },
      {
        label: '# of Votes 2',
        data: [15, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this.  This ticks: beginAtZero:true made it works for me

Comment: Hey I tried stacked bar charts in my code, and then even used the same code that you have, but I can't see the labels (# of Votes 1, # of Votes 2) at the top. I just see those label when I hover on the bars. Any reason that you know of why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure that you provide an array of object(s), not just one object for `xAxis` and `yAxis`.

```
"options": {
    "scales": {
        "xAxes": [
            {
                "stacked": true
            }
        ],
        "yAxes": [
            {
                "stacked": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```