# How to represent data of one dataset using charjs as a stack group per day?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I work with Vue.js and chartjs ,  and I have several water consumption data at different times. I would like to represent this data as a stack group per day. But all the examples I found are made with at least two different categories of data. I would like a bar to be the concatenation of all daily consumption. [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7THzl.png) of representation that I would like to get with my data. I need help

Comment: If you group your data by day and use the time of day as category, you will have what you want.

Comment: After preparing a code pen that set out to answer your question [my codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yEqWLJ), I stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38970692/7750124) when looking for dummy data...Hopefully this should answer your question!

Comment: Thank you very much for your intervention. But my problem still remains. I have the following data: [  {"value": 10,
        "date": "2018-03-27T02:50:46.964Z"},
   {"value": 15,
        "date": "2018-03-27T14:10:0Z",
   },
      {
        "value": 5,
        "date": "2018-03-28T03:50:46.964Z",
   },
      {
        "value": 29,
        "date": "2018-03-28T11:00:46.964Z",
   },
      {
        "value": 33,
        "date": "2018-03-28T22:50:46.964Z",}] And from this data I would like to have two stacks, one stack collecting the data from 2018-03-27 and the other 2018-03-28

Comment: Thank you sir Paul Georg Podlech, but can you give me more details